# QML change Loader size depending on sourceComponent

Tags: qt, qml

I have an item like this, where i need to change the content dynamically, but sometimes I don't know what the content size is:

```
//MyItem.qml
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Column {
    property alias titleHeight: titleItem.height
    property alias titleColor: titleItem.color
    property alias contentHeight: content.height
    property alias contentItem: content.sourceComponent

    id: item

    Rectangle {
        id: titleItem
        width: parent.width
        color: "#00a1ed"
    }

    Loader {
        id: content
        width: parent.width
    }
}
```

How can I not specify contentHeigth and set content.heigth based on contentItem.heigth?
The use case is the following:

```
//MyPage.qml
Item {
    id: item
    
    MyItem {
        titleHeigth: parent.heigth * 0.1
        titleColor: "blue"
        contentItem: Column {
            //... some items inside the column are not visible depending on the 
            //configuration, so column has not a fixed size
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#loader-sizing-behavior), as long as you don't specify a size for the Loader, it should resize itself to the size of the loaded item.

Comment: Note, a key part of the problem here is likely that your Item in MyPage.qml is going to end up with 0 width because it isn't sizing to contain its child. You likely either should make MyItem the top component or use a Layout.